# Extension By zero maps functions in $L^P(\Omega)$ into functions in $L^P(\mathbb{R^N})$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Extension By zero maps functions in $L^P(\Omega)$ into functions in $L^P(\mathbb{R^N})$

let $u:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$  Define $\tilde{u}:\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$ by zero zero outside $\Omega$

$$\tilde{u}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
u(x) & if \; x\in \Omega \\ 
 0& if \;x \notin \Omega
\end{matrix}\right.$$

how to prove this Extension By zero maps functions in $L^P(\Omega)$ into functions in $L^P(\mathbb{R^N})$

Answer (score 0):

All you have to show is that $\bar{u}$ satisfies

$$\int_{\Bbb R^n} |\bar{u}(x)|^p\,dV <\infty.$$

Split the integral into two (fairly obvious) pieces to prove the result.